# (locally) cached file object in Python

Tags: python, file, caching, file-io

I'm often working with large data files which I need to access over the network (mostly via NFS, but sometimes also via CIFS). For performance reasons it would be good to cache these files on the local harddrive to minimize network use.

So basically I'm looking for a file-object which automatically takes care of the local caching, something along these lines:

```
import CachedFileObject as cfo
cfo.set_local_cache_dir("/tmp")
handle = cfo.open("/nfs/server1/bigdatafile.nc", "r") # copy file to /tmp, open the copy
# do stuff with the filehandle
del handle                                            # delete the local copy
```

I really only need this for **reading** files. If there should be an easy way to also get/implement file creation (or even writing), that would be a bonus.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you appreciate an overhead for copying whole file on first opening?

Comment: If there's a way around that overhead, that would be most wonderful -- however, if that's not possible / too hard to implement, I can live with the overhead

Comment: I'm sure you've considered this, but just to throw it in there, for file updates/creation you'll need to sync changes back to the original file at some point. To allow concurrent access, you'll may also need to considerer possible race conditions with multiple write instances.

Comment: of course, writing would be difficult. basically, I just need reading, as stated in the question. I edited to emphasize this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple solution (with full copy on open for read access and full copy on close with write access):

```
import os
import shutil

from tempfile import mkstemp

class CachedFileObject(object):

    def __init__(self, cache_dir="/tmp"):
        self.cache_dir = cache_dir
        self.local_file = None
        self.local_path = None
        self.remote_path = None
        self.mode = None

    def open(self, path, mode="r", buffering=-1):
        if self.local_file and not self.local_file.closed:
            raise ValueError("Already open")
        fd, self.local_path = mkstemp(dir=self.cache_dir)
        os.close(fd)
        try:
            if "r" in mode and not os.path.exists(path):
                raise ValueError("No such remote file")
            if os.path.exists(path):
                # have remote file
                self._cache_remote(path, self.local_path)
            self.local_file = open(self.local_path, mode=mode, buffering=buffering)
            self.mode = mode
            self.remote_path = path
        except Exception as e:
            os.unlink(self.local_path)
            raise

        return self

    def close(self):
        self.local_file.close()
        try:
            if set("wa+").intersection(set(self.mode)):
                # have writes, sync file back to remote side
                self._sync_remote(self.remote_path, self.local_path)
        finally:
            os.unlink(self.local_path)

    def _cache_remote(self, remote_path, local_path):
        # simple cp
        shutil.copy(remote_path, local_path)

    def _sync_remote(self, remote_path, local_path):
        shutil.copy(local_path, remote_path)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if self.local_file is not None:
            return getattr(self.local_file, attr)
        else:
            raise ValueError("File is not opened")
```

Created object will behavior as regular file, and just copy/sync on open/close.

Usage:

```
f = CachedFileObject(cache_dir="/your/tmp/dir")
f.open("/path/to/remote/file")
# ..your f.read()'s here..
f.close()
```

Comment: I'm probably being dumb but I don't see how this would work as you're not extending the `file` class.

Comment: Magic hides in `__getattr__` method - when you access attribute of object and it not found (i.e. `seek` in this class), the `__getattr__` is being invoked with this attribute name as string. Then, my realization checks that real file object exists and return attribute from that file object.
Call order looks like this: `f.seek(42)` -> `f.__getattr__("seek")` -> `getattr(self.local_file, "seek")` equivalent to `self.local_file.seek` -> `__getattr__` returns `self.local_file.seek` -> `self.local_file.seek(42)`

Answer (score 3):

I would use the operating system for file caching. NFS mounts can be set to cache with `-o fsc` and SMB mounts already have some caching on by default.

Comment: yes, that would be ideal. however, it requires root access to the machine I'm working on, which I don't have.